# First-countable sets and closure

Tags: general-topology

I just have a quick question. I've been looking up first-countable sets, and quickly made it to the proposition:

$X$ is first-countable $\implies (A \subseteq X$ is closed iff it is sequentially closed$)$.

The proof is alright but I've been wondering a bit more about it and couldn't find many answers. So I apologize if the question has been asked already.

Is this an equivalence? Or are there non-first-countable sets in which the property still holds?

And also, I've been kind of struggling with finding a good example of a space in which closure and sequential closure are not equivalent. I am quite new to those kinds of topological considerations and can't come up with a lot of examples of sets that are not first-countable, I guess that's not helping. So if you happen to know of a good example, I would be really grateful!

Thanks :)

Comment: Examples of spaces that are not 1st-countable (with the usual topology on $\Bbb R $): (1). The Tychonoff product on $\Bbb R^k$  where $ k$ is an uncountable cardinal; (2). The box product on $\Bbb R^{\aleph_0}.$ (3). The maximal (Cech-Stone) compactification $\beta \Bbb N$ of the discrete space $\Bbb N$ (which is homeomorphic to the Walmann extension $w\Bbb N)$. (4). The quotient space $\Bbb R/E$  where  $xEy$ iff $(x=y\lor \{x,y\}\subset \Bbb N)$. However  none of these is an example for your main Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is Lemma 21.2 (the sequence lemma) in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be a topological space; let $A \subset X$. If there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$, then $x \in \overline{A}$; the converse holds if $X$ is metrizable.

Thus according to this result, the sequential closure of any set in a topological space is contained in the closure of the set.

And, if the topology of the space coincides with that determined by some metric on that space, then the closure of any set is also contained in the sequential closure.

Here is Theorem 30.1 (a) in Munkres' *Topology*, 2nd edition:

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. If there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$, then $x \in \overline{A}$; the converse holds if $X$ is first-countable.

Thus in any first-countable space, sequential closures are contained in closures, and in any first-countable metrizable space, closures are contained in sequential closures.

However, closures need not always be contained in sequential closures. For an explanation, please refer to Examples 1 and 2, Sec. 21, in Munkres' *Topology*, 2nd edition. And, please also refer to Example 3, Sec. 28, in the same text.

Should you have any problems making sense of these examples, please feel free to contact me! I'd be glad to be of help!

Comment: Saaqib. Clear answer, nice.

Comment: That is indeed a very clear answer, thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 1):

A space where any set is closed iff it is sequentially closed, has a name: it’s called a *sequential space*, unsurprisingly. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) has some info on them. It’s an old theorem (Franklin, IIRC) that $X$ is sequential iff it is the quotient space of a first countable space.

So e.g. to we take the quotient of $\Bbb R$ where we identify $\Bbb Z$ to a point we have an example of a non-first countable but sequential space. So being sequential is not equivalent to being first countable but close enough to it: a quotient of a first countable space.

The co-countable topology on $\Bbb R$ is not sequential at all. Any space with non-countable tightness ( like large product and function spaces ) are also common examples. 
E.g. in $X=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$, in the product topology, the set $\Sigma$ of all functions $f$ where $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ is at most countable (so "almost all" values are $0$) is sequentially closed in $X$ but not closed (even dense). It's also sequentially compact but not compact e.g.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. That's quite a mind-blowing result (it being true for quotients of first countable spaces only). Thanks! :)